# how to detect the button class that clicks on show in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following element

```
<button type="button" class='launch' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
<button type="button" class='boom' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Boom </button>
```

and I have an event listener:

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function () {   

       // how do I check if button has class launch or boom? 
})
```

how do I check if button has class launch or boom inside the function?
or in other words the question is how do I get the button that triggers this action inside this function.

Comment: it depends on what button you want to check. better use onclick and bind it on the buttons..and like the answer below says, use .hasClass() method of jQuery

Comment: what do you mean by depends on what button to check?

Comment: Why not listening to the `click` event?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get the trigger button in the `show` event

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery [.hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method to check whether the class exsists.

```
$('#element').hasClass('launch'); // returns true or false;
```

try the code below. Please add the `.myModalbtn` class to both buttons

```
$('.myModalbtn').on('hidden', function () {   

       $(this).hasClass('launch')) // if the it has launch class -> returns true else false;
});
```

Comment: but I have no access to the button inside the myModal.

Comment: I don't know how to get the button, I need to get the button that triggers this modal to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate class for each button like `.modalBtn` for example and do:

```
$('.modalBtn').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('launch')) showModal($('.launch'));
else if ($(this).hasClass('boom')) showModal($('.boom'));
});

function showModal( $btn ) {


//insert code to show modal (you can find it in the bootstrap javascript docs. Now you have $btn object to use.



}
```